# Pandas extract rows based on complex condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe:

```
            source         target  weight
24517        class         social      31
24356        class    proletariat      29
16189   bourgeoisi          class      29
24519        class        societi      29
24710        class           work      28
15375   bourgeoisi          class      26
23724        class         condit      24
24314        class          polit      24

...
```

How can I create a new dataframe that consists of:

```
            source         target  weight
24517        class         social      31 # because it's the strongest pair for 'class'
24356        class    proletariat      29 # bc it's the strongest for 'proletariat'
16189   bourgeoisi          class      29 # bc strongest for 'bourgeoisi'
24519        class        societi      29 # bc strongest for 'societi'
24710        class           work      28 # bc strongest for 'work'
```

But not for example:

```
15375     bourgeoisi          class      26 # bc it is not the strongest pair for either 'bourgeoisi' or 'class'

...
```

---

Alternative dataframe for testing. The code is supposed to drop line three (index 8):

```
0     ape    dog       3
1     ape   hors       3
8     dog   hors       2
2     ape     la       1
```

Comment: Can you explain when should a row be discarded? What are the rules for dropping a line in other words.

Comment: A line should be dropped if it is not the line with the highest 'weight' for either the 'source' or the 'target'

Comment: In your first example desired output, you have 4 instances with the same value for `source`, is that not contradicting?

Comment: No, see the `#` comments to that output.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({"source": ["class", "class", "bourgeoisi",
                            "class", "class", "bourgeoisi",
                            "class", "class"],
                 "target": ["social", "proletariat", "class",
                            "societi", "work", "class", "condit",
                            "polit"],
                 "weight": [31, 29, 29, 29, 28, 26, 24, 24]})

grouped = data.groupby(['source', 'target']).max().sort_values('weight', ascending=False).reset_index()
```

Result:

```
       source       target  weight
0       class       social      31
1  bourgeoisi        class      29
2       class  proletariat      29
3       class      societi      29
4       class         work      28
5       class       condit      24
6       class        polit      24
```

Explanation: we group the records by source and target and choose the records with maximum weight in each group, then sort values in descending order by weight and finally reset index to get source and target back into columns.

**[EDIT]** Given the examples I think you just need to group by 'target':

```
data2 = pd.DataFrame({"source": ["ape", "ape", "dog", "ape"],
                      "target": ["dog", "hors", "hors", "la"],
                      "weight": [3, 3, 2, 1]})

grouped = data2.groupby(['target']).max().sort_values('weight', ascending=False).reset_index()
grouped = grouped[data2.columns.tolist()]  # bring back the column order
print(grouped)
```

Result:

```
  source target  weight
0    ape    dog       3
1    dog   hors       3
2    ape     la       1
```

Comment: I tried this code with the alternative testing dataframe (edit in original post) and it did not drop the desired line.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this alternative:

```
result = data.sort_values('weight').groupby(['source','target'])['weight'].apply(lambda x: x.iloc[-1]).reset_index()
```

What this does:

1. Group all rows by `['source','target']`
2. Within each resulting group, sort by `'weight'`
3. Pick the last entry for each group, since ordering is by default from smaller to greater value.
4. Reset index to bring `['source','target']` back as columns rather as index.

Go take a coffee break and think of the next task.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Looks great! But, unfortunately, I get `AttributeError: Cannot access callable attribute 'sort_values' of 'SeriesGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method`

Comment: Hmm.... code seems good to me, but the resulting dataframe has the same row count as the first one...

Comment: I tried it again and I see that row `bourgeoisi        class      26` is dropped. Are you doing something different?

Comment: should `class` be `source`?

Comment: @textnet Yes, you are right. I wrote it correct in the oneliner, but wrong in the explanation! I've edited now.

Comment: I tried this code with the alternative testing dataframe (edit in original post) and it did not drop the desired line.

Answer (score 0):

Your dataframe essentially represents a weighted edgelist of a graph and you want to find out the max weight rows for all nodes which are distributed in two separate columns, in order to use `groupby()` syntax from `pandas`, you need to converge the nodes into a single column by either reshaping your data frame or replicating and concatenating, here is an option with the concatenation:

```
idx = (pd.concat([df, df.rename(columns={'source': 'target', 'target': 'source'})])
       # switch the source and target columns and concatenate to the original data frame

       .groupby('source', group_keys=False)
       # now the source column contains all the nodes, you can group by it

       .apply(lambda g: g.weight == g.weight.max())[lambda x: x].index.drop_duplicates())
       # for each node find out the max weight rows index for subsetting/filtering

df.loc[idx,:]
#           source       target   weight
#16189  bourgeoisi        class       29          # max for bourgeoisi
#24517       class       social       31          # max for class and social
#23724       class       condit       24          # max for condit
#24314       class        polit       24          # max for polit
#24356       class  proletariat       29          # max for proletariat
#24519       class      societi       29          # max for societi
#24710       class         work       28          # max for work
```

Comment: I tried this code with the alternative testing dataframe (edit in original post) and it did not drop the desired line.

Comment: I just tested the code, the line three is dropped. Note that you need to call `df.loc[idx, :]` for the line to be dropped or `df = df.loc[idx, :]`

Comment: I tested it now, and as line with index `0` it outputs `0    hors    dog`, which means that line three has not been dropped from the outputted df.

Comment: What version of pandas are you running? I am using a filter `[lambda x: x]` here which only works after version ~0.18.0.

Answer (score 0):

And for fun - Here is the answer in one line of code

```
pd.concat([df.assign(var_type = lambda x: x['source']),
           df.assign(var_type = lambda x: x['target'])])\
  .sort_values(['var_type', 'weight'], ascending=[True, False])\
  .groupby('var_type')\
  .first().reset_index(drop=True)
```

You can first add a unique id to each row and then use melt to put the source and target in one column and reattach the source and target to the long table. This long table now makes it easy to get the max.

```
df['id'] = np.arange(len(df))
df1 = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['id', 'weight'], var_name='var_type', value_name='label')
df2 = df1.merge(df[['id', 'source', 'target']], on='id')
df3 = df2.sort_values(['label', 'weight'], ascending=[True, False])
df3.groupby(['label']).first().reset_index(drop=True)[['source', 'target', 'weight']]

       source       target  weight
0  bourgeoisi        class      29
1       class       social      31
2       class       condit      24
3       class        polit      24
4       class  proletariat      29
5       class       social      31
6       class      societi      29
7       class         work      28
```

Comment: What do the first two lines do? What is `df0` and `df.copy`?

Comment: Its meaningless. It was just for me to preserve the original dataframe. I've changed the answer to remove that line